# Is box-sizing: border-box safe to use with max-width and min-width?

Tags: html, css, border-box

I've been reading on a couple of older resources that the use of `max-width` and `min-width` is buggy when combined with `box-sizing: border-box`. Does anyone else combine `max/min-width` with `box-sizing: border-box` and have any issues?

I plan to build a site with `* {box-sizing: border-box}` set globally for all elements but need to also use max-width but don't want to if it's going to cause issues.

Comment: I guess the main concern, is when child elements specify max-width: 100%, does that change the measurement, is it now relative to the border-box width or content box width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no issues that I'm aware of. Bear in mind though that when `border-box` is used, `padding` and `border` heights and widths are effectively consumed by the total height and width of the element. With this, for instance, specifying both a `max-height` of 100px and `padding-bottom` of 100px will make your element exactly 100px in height; not 200px. If you wanted 100px height and 100px bottom padding, you'd need to give your element a `max-height` of 200px.

Here is a [**JSFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/85rsQ/) using `border-bottom` to illustrate the difference.